# CKEditor5 placeholder config is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, ckeditor

I am trying to use a custom build CKEditor 5. This editor is based on `BalloonBlockEditor`.

Hereby you san see the custom build output:

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2014-2023, CKSource Holding sp. z o.o. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license
 */
import BalloonBlockEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-balloon/src/ballooneditor.js';
import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment.js';
import Autoformat from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat/src/autoformat.js';
import AutoImage from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/autoimage.js';
import AutoLink from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/autolink.js';
import BlockQuote from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote/src/blockquote.js';
import BlockToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/toolbar/block/blocktoolbar.js';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold.js';
import CKFinderUploadAdapter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder/src/uploadadapter.js';
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials.js';
import FontFamily from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontfamily.js';
import FontSize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontsize.js';
import GeneralHtmlSupport from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-html-support/src/generalhtmlsupport.js';
import Heading from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading.js';
import HorizontalLine from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-horizontal-line/src/horizontalline.js';
import Image from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image.js';
import ImageCaption from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagecaption.js';
import ImageInsert from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageinsert.js';
import ImageResize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageresize.js';
import ImageStyle from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagestyle.js';
import ImageToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagetoolbar.js';
import ImageUpload from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageupload.js';
import Indent from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent/src/indent.js';
import Italic from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic.js';
import Link from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link.js';
import LinkImage from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/linkimage.js';
import List from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/list.js';
import ListProperties from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/listproperties.js';
import MediaEmbed from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed/src/mediaembed.js';
import MediaEmbedToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed/src/mediaembedtoolbar.js';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph.js';
import PasteFromOffice from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office/src/pastefromoffice.js';
import Strikethrough from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/strikethrough.js';
import Style from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-style/src/style.js';
import Table from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/table.js';
import TableCaption from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tablecaption.js';
import TableCellProperties from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tablecellproperties';
import TableToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tabletoolbar.js';
import TextTransformation from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing/src/texttransformation.js';
import Underline from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/underline.js';

class Editor extends BalloonBlockEditor {}

// Plugins to include in the build.
Editor.builtinPlugins = [
    Alignment,
    Autoformat,
    AutoImage,
    AutoLink,
    BlockQuote,
    BlockToolbar,
    Bold,
    CKFinderUploadAdapter,
    Essentials,
    FontFamily,
    FontSize,
    GeneralHtmlSupport,
    Heading,
    HorizontalLine,
    Image,
    ImageCaption,
    ImageInsert,
    ImageResize,
    ImageStyle,
    ImageToolbar,
    ImageUpload,
    Indent,
    Italic,
    Link,
    LinkImage,
    List,
    ListProperties,
    MediaEmbed,
    MediaEmbedToolbar,
    Paragraph,
    PasteFromOffice,
    Strikethrough,
    Style,
    Table,
    TableCaption,
    TableCellProperties,
    TableToolbar,
    TextTransformation,
    Underline
];

// Editor configuration.
Editor.defaultConfig = {
    toolbar: {
        items: [
            'heading',
            '|',
            'alignment',
            'fontFamily',
            'fontSize',
            '|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'underline',
            'link',
            '|',
            'indent',
            'outdent'
        ]
    },
    language: 'tr',
    blockToolbar: [
        'imageUpload',
        'blockQuote',
        'insertTable',
        'bulletedList',
        'numberedList'
    ],
    image: {
        toolbar: [
            'imageTextAlternative',
            'toggleImageCaption',
            'imageStyle:inline',
            'imageStyle:block',
            'imageStyle:side',
            'linkImage'
        ]
    },
    table: {
        contentToolbar: [
            'tableColumn',
            'tableRow',
            'mergeTableCells',
            'tableCellProperties'
        ]
    }
};

export default Editor;
```

Even setting the placeholder config does not seem to be working. Here is the react component:

```
import CustomEditorSetup from "ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor";
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const CustomEditor = ({
  content,
  onChange,
}: {
  content?: string;
  onChange: (data: string) => void;
}) => {
  const config = {
    title: {
      placeholder: "Type the title here!",
    },
    placeHolder: "Type the content here!",
  };

  return (
    <CKEditor
      config={config}
      editor={CustomEditorSetup}
      data={content || ""}
      onChange={(event: any, editor: any) => {
        const data = editor.getData();
        onChange(data);
      }}
      onReady={(editor: any) => {
        editor.editing.view.focus();
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default CustomEditor;
```

Here is an output:
[image: not working placeholder]

Answer (score 0):

So basically,

The first issue is the wrong config name. Instead of `placeHolder`, it should be `placeholder`.

The other issue is that the `Title` plugin is missing in the Editor build.

It can be updated via [online builder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/) since it is a custom build.